# Remove link to root node from child nodes in d3 tree

Tags: d3.js

I followed this [blog](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1093025) to build an indented collapsible tree. I need a small modification in this. I want this tree to be without root. This might sound stupid but this is what I need. Now, two main components of d3 tree are nodes and links. I tricked a workaround to hide the nodes using this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40177670/5644090) and setting height factor as 0 for root node and label as "". Hence, the root node is not visible anymore. However, I failed to do any trick related to hiding the links from 24 child nodes to root. So, all the child nodes appear to be linked to a "no name" root node. I want to hide any link to the root of the tree. NOTE: All the 24 child nodes have sub-child. Below is partly code of link which isn't working.

```
// Update the links
var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
    .data(tree.links(nodes), function(d) { return d.target.id; });

link.enter().insert("path", "g")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
    })
    .transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", diagonal);

// Transition links to their new position.
link.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", diagonal);

// Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
link.exit().transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
    })
    .remove();

// Stash the old positions for transition.
nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the display property on your link elements

```
link.enter().insert("path", "g")
.attr("class", "link")
.attr("d", function(d) {
    var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
    return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
})
.style("display", function (d) {
   if (d.depth == 1) { //Is top link                                
         return 'none';
   }
 })
.transition()
.duration(duration)
.attr("d", diagonal);
```

This would hide all links with a depth of 1 but still show the other ones

Comment: Doesn't makes difference in the output. Also, I tried     .attr("class", function(d){ if(d.source.depth > 0){ return "link";}}) but didn't help.